# Why does not bind() or apply() work here, but call() does?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, prototype

Take this very simple framework I am experimenting with (so that I can learn JavaScript's function prototype more in depth.)

```
(function(){
var app = {
    ui: {
        app: document.querySelector('.app'),
        settings: document.querySelector('.settings'),
    },
    actions: 'click settings openSidebar'
    ,
    functions: {
        openSidebar: function(e){
            console.log(this); // <- expected value of this is 'app.ui'
        }
    },
    run: function(){
        var a1 = this.actions.split("\n");
        var a2 = this.actions.split(" ");

        var self = this;
        this.ui[a2[1]].addEventListener(a2[0], function(e){
            app.functions.openSidebar.call(self.ui,e);
        });
    }
};
app.run();
})();
```

This works great. Output from console is:

> Object {ui: Object, actions: "click settings openSidebar", functions: Object, run: function}

However, when I try to do it like this:

```
var self = this;
this.ui[a2[1]].addEventListener(a2[0], function(e){
    app.functions.openSidebar(e);
}.bind(this));
```

The context of `this` in `openSidebar()` is openSidebar (aka bind has no effect). Console output:

> Object {openSidebar: function}

However, when I try to use the `apply` function, like so:

```
app.functions.openSidebar.apply(self.ui,e);
```

It works fine (`this` in openSidebar is `app.ui`) EXCEPT that the argument (`e`) does not get passed, so `e == undefined`.

Here goes:

**1. Why does not bind work (at all) in the first example?**

**2. Why does apply work without passing arguments (the `e` (event))?**

And for added brownie points:

**3. Why does call work as expected?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does not bind work (at all) in the first example?

It "works", it just doesn't do what you expect.

Inside your anon function `this` is indeed the value set by `bind`. However, when you then call a function that is also a property of an object (`functions.openSidebar`) then for that invocation `this` is automatically bound to that object inside the function (i.e. `this === functions`). The value of `this` from the parent context is never "inherited" down the call chain.

> Why does apply work without passing arguments (the `e` (event))?

Because `apply` tries to pull out the arguments for the call from its own second argument `e` by treating it as an array. This means that its `length` property is checked first; your event object doesn't have a `length` so `apply` gets the `undefined` value produced and effectively behaves as if you had passed in an empty array. See the [annotated ES5 reference for the details](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.3).

> Why does call work as expected?

This is a strange question. Why would it *not* work? You are using it exactly like it's meant to be used.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, Jon. It helps a great deal. And I must agree, question #3 was a strange question in retrospect :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. You'll need to do this:

   `this.ui[a2[1]].addEventListener(a2[0], app.functions.openSidebar.bind(this));`

bind returns you a new function with a manually set context of whatever you pass in. Because you're not using bind on the right function, you're calling your function with `app.functions` to the left of the invoked function, which henceforth is known as `this` inside the invoked function!

1. Apply takes arguments as an array, not named parameters...
2. I can't explain the third without saying that that is how call works!

Comment: Thank you! To the point, even with a working code example. Appreciated